# PowerShell - Strip .exe from program call

Tags: powershell, executable

I really like the new PowerShell (7.2.4, in my case). However, I have to run certain programs that require a specific syntax:

```
$$ <prog> <ending>
```

`<prog>` is the name of the program, e.g. `test`, while the argument could be anything, e.g. `this`. The tricky part is that the program internally searches for a file that is called
like `test_this.cfg`, rejecting its own name (`test`), the underscore and the file extension (`.cfg`). So the correct call would be:

```
$$ test this
```

This program was originally designed for a Linux environment, where the executable itself has no file extension on its own and therefore this call works. But now that I am on Windows, it has to be an `.exe` file, otherwise it is not being executed (Windows then asks what to do with this file). The PowerShell call then looks like this (the `.\` are being added automatically by PowerShell):

```
$$ .\test this
```

but internally, the `.exe` extension seems to be there still, because the programm tells me that it cannot find a file called `test.exe_this.cfg` (of course it cannot, the name is `test_this.cfg`). Is there any way the PowerShell can simply ignore the `.exe` extension of the program, just like the default Windows CommandLine does?

Unfortunately, I'm not the program developer, so I cannot extend its functionalities to understand such patterns as well.

Comment: Can't you just rename the target config file to `test.exe_this.cfg`?

Comment: Since this is a recurring thing and still everything has to be transferrable to Linux as well... no, I can't.

Comment: With any config management system I'm aware of (or even if you are using scripts), you should be able to easily use one config file name for Windows and another for Linux. Do this as a workaround until the maintainers of `test.exe` fix their code (and you should report the issue too!)

Answer (score 3):

[Bender the Greatest's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72320426/45375) explains why a proper solution isn't possible without modifying the target program to account for the fact that executable files on Windows have filename extensions, typically `.exe`.

If you cannot modify the target program, here are potential **workarounds**:

- Install [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and directly run the *Linux* executable there; e.g.:

  ```
   wsl -e ./test this
  ```
- Before running the *Windows* executable, create *symlinks* that effectively redirect file names such as `test.exe_this.cfg` to `test_this.cfg`

  - Note: Unless you have Developer Mode enabled in Windows, creating symlinks (symbolic links) requires *elevation*.

    ```
    # Create the symlink(s).
    Get-ChildItem test_*.cfg | ForEach-Object {
       New-Item -Type SymbolicLink ($_.Name -replace '^.[^_]+', '$&.exe') -Target $_.Name
    }

    # Now the target program should be able to find the right file
    # via its associated symlink.
    .\test this
    ```
- Create a *hard link* to your *executable* whose file name has *no* extension, and invoke the hard link instead - see below.

  - **Caveat**: This relies on PowerShell interpreting an *empty* `$env:PATHEXT` entry to mean: consider extension-less file names executables. While this currently works (as of PowerShell 7.2.4), it is unclear whether this behavior is *by design*. By contrast, `cmd.exe` *ignores* empty `$env:PATHEXT` entries, so the solution won't work there.

```
# The path to your executable.
$originalExe = '.\test.exe'

# Create a temp. dir to house the temporary hard link.
$tmpDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()))

# Create the hard link, without a filename extension, which
# points to the same file data as the original executable.
$tmpExeWithoutExtension = 
  New-Item -Type HardLink `
           (Join-Path  $tmpDir ([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($originalExe))) `
            -Target (Convert-Path $originalExe)

# Temporarily add an empty entry to $env:PATHEXT, so
# that PowerShell considers extension-less files executable.
$env:PATHEXT += ';'

# Invoke the hard link.
# The executable will now see the hard link's path as its own
# path in argv[0].
& $tmpExeWithoutExtension this

# Clean up.
$env:PATHEXT = $env:PATHEXT.Substring(0, $env:PATHEXT.Length-1)
Remove-Item -Recurse -LiteralPath $tmpDir
```

Note: The above creates the hard link on demand, and deletes it afterwards. You may choose to create a persistent hard link instead; if you choose to create it in the same directory as the original executable, you must invoke it *by its full path* in order to disambiguate it from the original executable, and another *caveat* applies there: it is also unclear whether this method of disambiguation works by design - see [GitHub issue #7769](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7769).

Comment: I was avoiding mentioning symlinks as a workaround, but yeah this would work for getting the config to load. But, if you're at an impasse between renaming the file or hacking a new entrypoint in for the program.... the safer route would be to simply work with the current limitations and use an OS-specific configuration file name. Depending on what the program does, symlinking an alternate entrypoint could break things, for example, if it uses its own filename as part of it's *own* configurations and data.

Comment: Ah wait, I mis-read your answer. You are suggesting to symlink the *config file* as a workaround, not the executable. That's fine to do here.

Comment: Indeed, @BendertheGreatest. You can't actually create an extension-less symlink to an executable in Windows in a way that makes the symlink act like the console application it targets. In PowerShell, you can invoke such a symlink, but (a) it'll be opened like a document and (b) the target program still uses its own filename.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I appreciate that you made me test it out, though :)

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, turns out there _is_ a way to make this work in PowerShell, with either symbolic or hard links - though I wonder if it works by design. Please see my update, which shows a hard link-based approach (I chose a hard link, because creating one doesn't potentially require elevation).

Comment: Thanks for this great "workaround". I will first go with the developer and ask him if he can do anything about it (I don't think so), then I will try and see if I can get your solution to work. Any ideas why the "standard" command line in Windows can handle it, though?

Comment: @s6hebern, `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) _ignores_ empty `$env:PATHEXT` entries, so the solution won't work there - it never considers extension-less file names executable; I've also added this info to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, because on Windows the file extension is still part of the file name. This is not a problem with PowerShell, it is simply how Windows execution works. The issue needs to be fixed in `test.exe`, the real problem is that `test.exe` has a bug on Windows when generating the file name that needs to be fixed.

Comment: That's what I thought, so I need to find a workaround (like the suggested ones). Still wondering why the "normal" command line works, though.